# reverse file character by character using tac

Tags: tac

I want to use the `tac`to reverse a text file character by character. On the info page for coreutils I found an example saying: #Reverse a file character by character `tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]'`

However running `tac -r -s` seems to open standard input instead of printing the file. What does `'x\|[^x]'` mean and what should I be doing?

I also noted that the output for `tac [file]` and `tac -r [file]` are same and they're the same as `cat [file]`. Still can't figure out char by char reverse.

Comment: So did you try the command it told you to or not?

Comment: Are you talking about reversing the order of the lines and then reversing the order of the characters of the lines as well? Do you have `rev`?

Comment: Reversing characters not lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To reverse a file character-by-character using `tac`, use:

```
tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]'
```

[This is documented in `info tac`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#tac-invocation):

> ```
> # Reverse a file character by character.
> tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]'
> ```

[`-r` causes the separator to be treated as a regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#index-_002dr). [`-s SEP` uses `SEP` as the separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#index-_002ds-1). `x\|[^x]` is a regular expression that matches every character (those that are `x`, and those that are not `x`).

```
$ cat testfile
abc
def
ghi
$ tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]' testfile

ihg
fed
cba%
$
```

`tac file` is not the same as `cat file` unless `file` has only one line. `tac -r file` is the same as `tac file` because the default separator is `\n`, which is the same when treated as a regular expression and not.

Comment: Wouldn't `.` work just as well as the regex? What does this match that `.` doesn't? `\n`?

Comment: @muru Yes, if you use `.` it swaps bytes over the `\n`: `printf 'ab\ncd\n'|tac -r -s . |hexdump -c` -> `\n   d  \n   c   b   a`, and `tac -r -s . | tac -r -s .` isn't idempotent.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not concerned about the [LF character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (see mosvy's comments), then it is much more efficient to use `rev` rather than `tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]'`, piping it to `tac` if needed.

```
$ cat testfile
abc
def
ghi
$ rev testfile
cba
fed
ihg
$ rev testfile|tac
ihg
fed
cba
```

This solution is way cheaper than `tac -r -s 'x\|[^x]'` because regular expressions tend to slow things down quite dramatically.

Comment: Indeed. A ~tenfold speedup. But it's not actually reversing the input character by character: in `printf "foo\nbar\n" | rev | tac`, the output will not start with `"\n"` and end with `"f"`, but start with `"r"` and end with `"\n"` ;-)

Comment: you can replace the `rev` with `perl -ne 'print scalar reverse'`, though.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for the hint, added a warning. ;)